# How to display an UIImage in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, uiimage

I simply would like to display an image which is part of the app.
When executing the following code, my image is `nil`.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "back.png");
```

The "back.png" is stored in my `"Images.xcassets"` folder of my project.

How to load the image from within the app folders?

(Loading the Image from a path is working for me, but I do not know how to reference an image stored in the project itself)

Answer (score 4):

With the latest **Xcode 8.3** its much easier to adding any image,  Using **Image Literal** option.

Just select any image from assets.

```
let image = //type and select Image Literal option, and select image from as per below reference
```

[image]

Comment: Great option, I was searched half hour so finally got it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the name of the Image Set, inside `Images.xcassets` that `back.png` is stored in, instead of the actual file name.

[image]

From the Asset Catalog above (obviously there would be some images in there though), you would use the code:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Image")
```

Have a look at [About Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) for more information.

Comment: I guess that is exactly what I do not understand. Where is this Image Set ?

Comment: ok. I just got it to work. But I still do not understand. In the project explorer I clicked on the Images.xcassets Folder and added the image by "new Image set". So I have to do this for every Image ?

Comment: I believe you do, yes. Image Sets are used for organising your images for different screen sizes. I would recommend looking at the link in my edited answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can just drag the images into your project Assets.xcassets, and yes you have to do this for every image you are using. @mcflysoft

Answer (score 0):

Don't use file extension if you place image in Images.xcassets. You need to use the name of the Image Set.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "back")
```